# Errors running laravel 5 under docker

Tags: docker, laravel-5

I try to install laravel 5.0/mysql"5.5"/php_version under docker and I can not site in browser and make seeding of app:
I have 3 config files:
docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3.1'

services:

    youtube_api_demo_app:
        build:
            context: ./web
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.yml

        container_name: youtube_api_demo_app_container
        environment:
            - APACHE_RUN_USER=#1000
        volumes:
            - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
        ports:
            - 8085:80
        working_dir: ${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}


    db:
        image: mysql:5.5.62
        restart: always
        environment: 
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - ${DB_PATH_HOST}:/var/lib/mysql


    adminer:
        image: adminer
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8086:8080
        links:
            - db


    youtube_api_demo_composer:
        image: composer:1.6
        container_name: youtube_api_demo_composer_container
        volumes:
            - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
        working_dir: ${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
        command: composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

.env:

```
# PATHS
DB_PATH_HOST=./databases
APP_PATH_HOST=./YoutubeAPI_Demo
APP_PTH_CONTAINER=/var/www/html/
```

web/Dockerfile.yml:

```
FROM php:5.6-apache
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y libpng-dev   nano  libmcrypt-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    pdo_mysql \
    mcrypt \
    && a2enmod \
    rewrite
```

and env of my app /YoutubeAPI_Demo/.env :

> APP_NAME=Laravel APP_ENV=local
>   APP_KEY=base64:4+BRJbKtSQ7Z7yBVkYxe+NxfLkVPBAG2Gm1I93Qwukc=
>   APP_DEBUG=true APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8085/ APP_SUBDIRECTORY=
>
> LOG_CHANNEL=stack
>
> DB_USERNAME=root DB_PASSWORD=1 DB_CONNECTION=mysql
>   DB_HOST=127.0.0.1:8086 DB_PORT=:8086 DB_DATABASE=youtube_api_demo

I am not sure if I set valid DB_HOST and DB_PORT parameters, actually I tried different.

1) I builded the app and entered the console, but I got error migrating:

```
# php artisan migrate                                                           
  [PDOException]                             
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

But I entered adminer and created the db: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbzYu.jpg

2) Entering in browser http://127.0.0.1:8085/ I got error :

```
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 8085 


 docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS                    NAMES
a51ccd12ae40        adminer                                "entrypoint.sh docke…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour                0.0.0.0:8086->8080/tcp   youtubeapi_demo_adminer_1
7f9ee8f14c9d        mysql:5.5.62                           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour                3306/tcp                 youtubeapi_demo_db_1
b2c47edaf616        youtubeapi_demo_youtube_api_demo_app   "docker-php-entrypoi…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour                0.0.0.0:8085->80/tcp     youtube_api_demo_app_container
3dcc1a4ce8f0        adminer                                "entrypoint.sh docke…"   5 weeks ago         Up 4 hours                      0.0.0.0:8083->8080/tcp   lprods_adminer_container
933d9fffaf76        postgres:9.6.10-alpine                 "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 weeks ago         Up 4 hours                      0.0.0.0:5433->5432/tcp   lprods_db_container
2f73a600b999        adminer                                "entrypoint.sh docke…"   6 weeks ago         Up 4 hours                      0.0.0.0:8082->8080/tcp   votes_docker_adminer_1
52ea479b8791        mysql:5.6.41                           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 weeks ago         Restarting (1) 34 seconds ago                            votes_docker_db_1
```

What are wrong in config options ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) In .env: you can use :

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db // THAT IS MYSQL container name
DB_PORT=3306
```

2) Try url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8085/public
```

with usual laravel 5 dirs settings